# Use variable in Pandas query

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to query a Pandas dataframe like this:

```
inv = pd.read_csv(infile)
inv.columns = ['County', 'Site', 'Role', 'Hostname'] 
clist = inv.County.unique()  # Get list of counties
for county in clist:  # for each county
    csub = inv.query('County == county')  # create a county subset
    # ... do stuff on subset
```

But I get an error:

```
pandas.core.computation.ops.UndefinedVariableError: name 'county' is not defined
```

I'm sure it's a trivial error, but I can't figure it out.  How do I pass a variable to the query method?

Comment: how about 'County == ' + county

Comment: `inv[inv['County'] == county]`

Comment: `inv.query('County ==@ county')`

Answer (score 112, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html), you can reference variables using `@`:

```
csub = inv.query('County == @county')
```

Answer (score 14):

### Format String Function

I found another (more generic) solution that might be interesting: The [`format` string function](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html) (for examples, see `6.1.3.2. Format examples`).

```
xyz = df.query('ColumnName >= {}'.format(VariableName))
```

The `{}` is replaced by `VariableName`.

### f-Strings

In addition, user [pciunkiewicz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11704802) mentioned in a comment another solution using so-called `f-strings` which were introduced in [Python 3.6](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) (August 2015):

```
xyz = df.query(f'ColumnName >= {VariableName}')
```

A more general `f-strings` example, taken from [here](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/):

```
>>> name = "Eric"
>>> age = 74
>>> f"Hello, {name}. You are {age}."
'Hello, Eric. You are 74.'
```

PS: I am new to Python.

Comment: You can clean this up using f-strings which were introduced in Python 3.6: `xyz = df.query(f'ColumnName >= {VariableName}')`.

Comment: ATTENTION: Simple string substitution might be unsafe in production, see here https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/13521#issuecomment-593900167